# Hibernate: composite-element results in delete+insert on every commit

Tags: java, hibernate

Here's a part of my mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="trx.domain">
    <class name="Master" table="master" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true">

        <set name="attributes" table="attribute" lazy="true"
            cascade="all" batch-size="10">
            <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
            <key>
                <column name="master_id" />
            </key>
            <composite-element class="Attribute">
                <many-to-one name="type" class="AttributeType"
                     not-null="true" column="attribute_type_id" lazy="false" />
                <property name="value">
                    <column name="value" />
                </property>
            </composite-element>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If I simply scan the `attributes` set, without any updates, Hibernate would still execute a batch of `delete` and `insert` operations on commit.

```
Hibernate: delete from attribute where master_id=? and attribute_type_id=?
Hibernate: delete from attribute where master_id=? and attribute_type_id=?
Hibernate: insert into attribute (master_id, attribute_type_id, value) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into attribute (master_id, attribute_type_id, value) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Why is it happening? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Hibernate Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-collections-mostefficientupdate)

> Because of the structure of a Set, Hibernate does not UPDATE a row when an element is "changed". Changes to a Set always work via INSERT and DELETE of individual rows.

If Hibernate tries to update your set even if you don't modify it, maybe your `equals` and `hashcode` implementations in `Attribute` class are broken?